# Multiprocessing Big Datasets in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bigdata

I'm new to multiprocessing in python and was wondering If I could do this for my data analysis.

### The code:

```
file1=open('./R.csv','r').readlines()
file2=open('./N.csv','r').readlines()
```

#### Defining the dictionary:

```
Dict1={}
Dict2={}
```

#### Storing file1 first column as dictionary elements:

```
    for k1 in range(0,len(file1)):
            d1=file2[k1].split(',')[0]
            Dict1[k1]=d1
#print(Dict1[1])
```

#### Storing file2 first column as dictionary elements:

```
for k2 in range(0,len(file2)):
        d2=file2[k2].split(',')[0]
        Dict2[k2]=d2
#print(new_Dict[0])
```

#### To check if the elements in Dict1 is same as Dict2 line by line, If so, print the matching line in file1 and file2:

```
for i in range(0,len(file1)):
        for j in range(0,len(file2)):
                if Dict1[i] in Dict2[j]:
                        print(Dict1[i]+","+file1[i].split(',')[1].strip()+","+file2[j].split(',')[1].strip())
```

This code works, but it takes a lot of time to complete the job since both the files are a huge dataset. I'm wanting to use all the 64 CPU clusters at my work station in the server. But don't know how...

I've tried to follow these links below, but somehow got stuck.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914821/producer-consumer-problem-with-python-multiprocessing
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sp7EhjLkFY4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aysceqdGFw8
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Many thanks. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. IMHO, I doubt that the approach you started is recommendable for the task you try to achieve. You are doing a lot of things "by hand" for which tasks there are libraries out there, which are suited better. I don't even think that `dict`s are the datatype you really want/need - your keys are just the integers representing the line number counts of your files... The values are lists of the column entries of each row... I think you should look at things like `numpy.genfromtxt()` or `pandas.read_table()` or sth similar...

Comment: At first: what exactly do you want to do? loading the contents of two files and check if all rows of the frist are contained in the second, not knowing about the order of th rows in both files...?

Comment: Hi SpghttCd, Many thanks for your response. I am trying to read and check if the contents (column 1) of file1 is present in file2 column 2 regardless of the order in the second file.

Comment: Ok, and how many rows per file are we talking about?

Comment: Hi SpghttCd, Many thanks for your response. I am trying to read and check if the contents (column 1) of file1 is present in file2 column 2 regardless of the order in the second file and prints the result. I have done this using nested for loop. This code works perfect, except that I'm trying to see if there's a faster way of processing the condition check for multiple lines in a file at the same time using multiprocessing and printing...i.e. trying to get the job done quicker...I'm all ears to any sugggestions. Many thanks.

Comment: By around 700,000 rows for each file.

Comment: By around 700,000 rows for each file

Answer (score 0):

I'd test at first using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df_r = pd.read_table('./R.csv', header=None)   # check if standard delimiter ',' works...
df_n = pd.read_table('./N.csv', header=None)   # ... otherwise add e.g. sep='\s+,\s+'

print(df_r[df_r[0].isin(df_n[1])])
```

Perhaps this is an approach which already works for you.

Comment: The below link was useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130929/how-to-compare-a-python-dictionary-key-with-a-part-of-another-dictionarys-key